# Pre increment and post increment function call

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
void add();
int i=2;
add(i++,--i);  
print("%d",i)      
}
void add(int a,int b)
{
print("%d %d",a,b);
}
```

/*what are a and b's value i am actually not getting the answer why b is 2 */

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score -1):

in line 6 where add() is called

first args is i++ so it will send value 2 ie value of i to the function and then add 1 now i=3.

second args is --i now it will subtract 1 and iwill now be 2 again and then send value 2 to function

So I think your answer will print
2 2 (that is value of a and b)
2 (that is value of i)

Comment: Are you sure because it is printing a=2 and b=2 in my system.